# AxWindowsMediaPlayer does not play audio/video from url?

Tags: windows-mobile, activex, windows-media-player

HI,

I am using activeXMediaPlayer to play files from url but each time I pass a url to it shows the message , "either the file is corrupted or player does not support the file format u are playing."  But when i run the same url on browser the file is downloaded and this downloaded file can be played on the media player.

I am not able to find out what the problem is . Because the same cod plays the local file and the downloaded files but not file from url

Although the same code worked few months ago for the urls

So is this my fault or some server related issues can affect this thing.

Please help me I am in big trouble.

Regards,

Madhup

Answer (score 1):

Check if your url contains space, media player can not uderstand when url contains space. I had a same problem and I replaced space by "_" then media can play my url.